# Access function location programmatically

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools, v8, console.log

Is it possible in code to access `["[[FunctionLocation]]"]` property that google chrome developer tools show when using console log on a function ?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The answer, for now, is **no**.

The `[[FunctionLocation]]` property you see in Inspector is added in [`V8Debugger::internalProperties()`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/f9fbaec39a201812c5e45c9b632f012ab3c531b7/src/inspector/v8-debugger.cc#L719-L721) in the debugger's C++ code, which uses another C++ function [`V8Debugger::functionLocation()`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/f9fbaec39a201812c5e45c9b632f012ab3c531b7/src/inspector/v8-debugger.cc#L831-L861) to gather information about the function. `functionLocation()` then uses a number of V8-specific C++ APIs such as [`v8::Function::GetScriptLineNumber()` and `GetScriptColumnNumber()`](https://github.com/v8/v8/blob/f9fbaec39a201812c5e45c9b632f012ab3c531b7/include/v8.h#L3685-L3694) to find out the exact information.

All APIs described above are exclusively available to C++ code, not JavaScript code. In other words, JavaScript code on the webpage does not have direct access to this information.

---

However, you may be able to get access to the properties using a Chrome extension. More recently, the V8 JavaScript engine used by Chrome has added support to access these properties through the [Chrome DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/). In particular, you can get the internal properties through the [`Runtime.getProperties`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#method-getProperties) call. Additionally, it [seems like](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#extension) Chrome extensions may be able to interact with the DevTools protocol through [`chrome.debugger`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/debugger.html).

A proof of concept for using the DevTools protocol in Node.js, which has direct access to the protocol using the [Inspector](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html) built-in module (helpfully mentioned by Mohamed in their answer):

```js
global.a = () => { /* test function */ };

const s = new (require('inspector').Session)();
s.connect();

let objectId;
s.post('Runtime.evaluate', { expression: 'a' }, (err, { result }) => {
  objectId = result.objectId;
});
s.post('Runtime.getProperties', { objectId }, (err, { internalProperties }) => {
  console.log(internalProperties);
});
```

yields

```js
[
  {
    name: '[[FunctionLocation]]',
    value: {
      type: 'object',
      subtype: 'internal#location',
      value: [Object],
      description: 'Object'
    }
  },
  {
    name: '[[Scopes]]',
    value: {
      type: 'object',
      subtype: 'internal#scopeList',
      className: 'Array',
      description: 'Scopes[2]',
      objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":1,"id":24}'
    }
  }
]
```

with Node.js v12.3.1.

Comment: This is true science, thanks for taking the deep dive on this and explaining it rather than speculations or witchcraft.

Comment: Timothy do you know the answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/56066523/1091309)? Trying to access `[[FunctionLocation]]` in a Chrome extension not Dev Tools.

Comment: @mike-pz I've answered that question, as well as augmented this answer with some additional information on extensions.

Answer (score 12):

I know that it has been a while when this question was posted. Now, I had the same problem. I need to access the function location on the runtime.

Fortunately, NodeJS did a great job by exposing some v8 internal properties through the [`inspector`](https://nodejs.org/api/inspector.html) module.

I have written a small module called [`func-loc`](https://github.com/midrissi/func-loc) that helps to retrieve a function location on the runtime.

Example:

```js
const { locate } = require('func-loc');

const fn = () => {
  console.log('Hello there');
};

(async () => {
  const result = await locate(fn);
  console.log(result);
  // Will result: { source: 'file://__BASE_FOLDER__/func-loc/this-file.js', line: 3, column: 12 }
})();
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

console.log can show the function name in Chrome with [limited language support](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/name).

I've found the function name useful in debugging callbacks and when using the [observer pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Observer_pattern). Note this requires naming functions to work (anonymous function names are obviously blank).

```
function myFn() {}

if (typeof myFn === 'function') {
  console.log('Name of function', myFn.name)
}
```

Outputs `Name of function myFn`

Comment: I won't downvote this answer because it might be useful for someone else, but `name` is part of the standard Function object definition, what OP is looking for is part of a new Google Chrome Dev Tools feature which additionally exposes the file name on which such function is defined as `[[FunctionName]] `