# How to get source code location from ES6 JavaScript class instance?

Tags: javascript, reflection, code-generation, classloading

I would like to generate some code from my object tree. In order to generate the required import statements, I need to find out the source code location for a given class from a class instance.

I am already able to get the expected name `MyClass` with

```
var name = instance.constructor.name;
```

but not the source code location

```
'/src/package/myClass.js'
```

=>How to do so?

For Java it would work like described here:

[Find where java class is loaded from](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/227486/find-where-java-class-is-loaded-from)

If I inspect the constructor in Chrome developer tools with dir(constructor), I can see some property

```
[[FunctionLocation]]: myClass.js:3
```

and if I hover over it, I can see the wanted path. How can I get that property programmatically?

[image]

**Edit**

Just found that [[FunctionLocation]] is not accessible:

[Access function location programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146373/access-function-location-programmatically)

Comment: check out [source maps](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Debugger/How_to/Use_a_source_map)

Comment: Just in case you don't already know, it can save some headaches to realize that JS doesn't actually have "classes" -- despite the `class` keyword and related syntax. (MDN explains: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible work around seems to be to call

```
determineImportLocation(){
    var stack = new Error().stack;
    var lastLine = stack.split('\n').pop();
    var startIndex = lastLine.indexOf('/src/');
    var endIndex = lastLine.indexOf('.js:') + 3;
    return '.' + lastLine.substring(startIndex, endIndex);
}
```

in the constructor of `MyClass` and store it for later access:

```
constructor(name){
    this.name = name;
    if(!this.constructor.importLocation){
        this.constructor.importLocation = this.determineImportLocation();
    }                       
}
```

That would however require to modify all classes that I would like to `import`. Please let me know if there is a solution that does not require to modify the class itself.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[document.currentScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/currentScript) works in all browser except IE. You can use it like this:

```
var script = document.currentScript;
var fullUrl = script.src;
```

Comment: +1 --if you need further browser support, you might want to check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2255689/how-to-get-the-file-path-of-the-currently-executing-javascript-code

Comment: document.currentScript is null for me on Chrome. I guess that this does not work for ES6 classes / modules?

Comment: It doesn't work for asynchronous code. Not sure about modules.

Comment: @Stefan where are you calling it from? It should work.

Comment: From within some ES6 module.