# Javascript: Retrieve file and line location of function during runtime

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

I am trying to get the file and line location of a function I saved in an object. If I am logging the object to the Chrome Dev Tools I see this:

[image]

Can I somehow from inside the code access `[[FunctionLocation]]`? Or is this something the Chrome Dev Tools add to the object? If so, is it possible to retrieve the function location when I am developing a Chrome Dev Tools extension or a Chrome extension?

Comment: [This should better be able to help answer your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41146373/access-function-location-programmatically), but it appears to be no.

Comment: Looks like you asked a two part question and rather than start another thread the second part of your questions was not answered by the above link and is what I am curious about as well.

1. Can you access it in dev tools from the console? The link says no, mind you that was a couple years ago. 

2. Are we able to access that from within an extension script? I have searched the APIs but cannot find it referenced and am developing an extension and I would like to find functions locations as part of the data points I am exposing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You still cannot access the internal properties through JavaScript.
2. The information is exposed through the Chrome DevTools Protocol, as an [`InternalPropertyDescriptor`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Runtime#type-InternalPropertyDescriptor). This is observable through for example Node.js:

   ```js
   global.a = () => { /* test function */ };

   const s = new (require('inspector').Session)();
   s.connect();

   let objectId;
   s.post('Runtime.evaluate', { expression: 'a' }, (err, { result }) => {
     objectId = result.objectId;
   });
   s.post('Runtime.getProperties', { objectId }, (err, { internalProperties }) => {
     console.log(internalProperties);
   });
   ```

   yields

   ```js
   [
     {
       name: '[[FunctionLocation]]',
       value: {
         type: 'object',
         subtype: 'internal#location',
         value: [Object],
         description: 'Object'
       }
     },
     {
       name: '[[Scopes]]',
       value: {
         type: 'object',
         subtype: 'internal#scopeList',
         className: 'Array',
         description: 'Scopes[2]',
         objectId: '{"injectedScriptId":1,"id":24}'
       }
     }
   ]
   ```

   with Node.js v12.3.1.

   Chrome extensions may interact with the Chrome DevTools protocol through [`chrome.debugger`](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/#extension). I am not familiar with how DevTools extensions work, but you may find the [Integrating with DevTools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/integrating) page to be insightful.