# Find module/file of a function handle

Tags: javascript, node.js

In NodeJS, Given a function handle, how to find the file or module where such function was declared?

For example:

```js
// File 1

import { test } from './file1'

function fileFile(fn: Function){
   //... here's my issue
}

console.log(findFile(test)) // Logs '~/a/b/file1.js'
```

```js
// File 2

export const test = ()=> true
```

I have tried different approaches, from using `v8` to `require`.
I cannot find a proper way to do this.
I thought of finding the `fn.toString()` contents but wont be so reliable.

Thoughts?

Comment: There is no direct way to do it is what I think. The reason being: functions can be passed around, re-assigned, and imported/exported across modules. There can be hacky inefficient way although. Having said that, If you have control over the codebase, one alternative is to **add metadata to your functions, which includes information about their source files**. You can then use this metadata to find the file where the function was declared.

Comment: I'm thinking about using decorators for this. It might be the only option. But before working on that I wanted to exhaust all possible options. 

Thanks for the reply @mandy8055

Comment: ECMAScript doesn't standardize this.  But I'm confident v8 stores it somewhere.  It's used when a script causes an error and reports a stacktrace with the filenames.  Be aware that some functions don't have origins with nice filenames / urls, such as those that were built from an `eval` instruction.  I do not think this is accessible via script via `v8` or `vm` modules, as you tried, but you may be able to write a native addon (likely ABI unstable) that pulls the info from the function. The chain is likely: function -> script -> source url but I can't point to the exact code yet. Still looking

Comment: For some reason I didn't see the `[[FunctionLocation]]` member within the Function.

Will report back to see if it's works. (node 18)

Comment: Update: Found this https://stackoverflow.com/a/55564765/6022629 by searching '[[FunctionLocation]]'. Checking it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even after searching and asking several AI bots. I did not find it.
But there was a solution.

I found by mere chance `[[FunctionLocation]]`, and then when I searched for that specific words, then I found `https://github.com/midrissi/func-loc`

With that I was good to go.